# jQuery.noConflict() with other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using my Jquery application along with other javascript libraries. When googled I came to know that Jquery.noConflict() is the solution to avoid conflict with other libraries. For testing purpose I added the scripts as given below in the head section of the html which is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/myJqueryScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype-1.7.1.0.js"></script>
```

But in some scenarios it may come at the bottom of other libraries as given below, which is conflicting.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype-1.7.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/myJqueryScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

That means my script will come before or after other libraries are called. Is there any good solution for this issue. Please correct me if this is not the syntax of Jquery.noConflict().

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, anyway, it seems to be in no control of you... I wonder how these pages are built? Looks like there's some server code which decided what scripts to append; could you show some of it here?

Comment: raina, actually my code is for populating a popup widget. When the user clicks a button on the page I will call this JQuery code. Since the page is already loaded it may contain other libraries so makes conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

I usually just wrap all my jquery code in this:

```
(function($){
  //use jquery $() here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1, because the approach is good in general. Yet it may not solve the OP's problem, because `jQuery` won't be defined here if the user's script precedes libraries. Besides, the OP may want to use another libraries here, and 'their' `$` will be lost here.

Comment: Yes @raina77ow thats the situation

Answer (score 0):

If `myJqueryScript.js` consist of your own jQuery code then you have to call `noConflict` before that like `var jQuery = $.noConflict();` now you have to use this `jQuery` variable that you created.But it should be called after the jquery has been included `jquery-1.2.6.js` in your case.But you are also having `prototype and mootools` which also use $ so you will have to get a `Dollar safe mode` of mootools http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/

Comment: THanks techie_28 but I cant handle anything except my script because rest of the things are coming as third party code

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I found the a convinient solution

[Using multiple versions of jQuery](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/)